# how undrestand what this code is : Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hex

It supposed to be Javascript:

```
var _0x172e=["2.8","5.67","*    exmpl|","data:audio/mp3;base64,SUQzAwAAAAAHdlRDT04AAAAHAAAAT3RoZXIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

```
A`AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/zuMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFZCUkkAAQbxAGQAAAgoAAAACAAHAAEAAgABAfgBsAFoALQA/AEgACQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/zqMAAYPNOPPdY2AE5aq/
ciCpGWTkTZ2xNU6gaEsBAQUhLA0x11y990TzYoDIb1OdFNt30f0CnMqKDIA5SIFBQMFs6AgEjAYWOmhHxmg4XpMHDwMLkAIYsPBBYYqam1NBqhgYACmOkI8RmKHRqzAakOGRrp21wdE4Bi6ZWgmfk4JEDOFA15mNqWjcVMzcLMIODVmI1xEGjkyE7NTJzGFg
7e9OpewFBmHFBlg4BAMyU3M1GQQUGytZrp+NGZgQcYcAEoOY2SmRhooJGfoZnJGTB4IAi9AqBmJjJi4OSAhk5SZGJpZomK8EYCYWImHgKdxioyYmDqcrCPYhPMFCQMHsiMHCwMHtnaxFUqwCAg4DcotmgvIoxHU5y2aAOBlM11z1iJqZoSy47N33fu/XcNQN
FdItTdYjXKJ92HrvYmudFcswgpCWVqnce09YJATEA4DCDWUJasaWhggQPAhgouZwbGXDhWBAUHMJA1vAwEMKCjCAIDBadcBIJC2iuJTI2AKnZfPyiMXq9uo/8bt6MD4Y8BsBcBdFKIoMSlzbTakcjSNY1Bun4pBPSXoMgJPVgfP/zmMAfTqPOnx+P8AGXgca
4KE2jFaepYg+7NI3VqlmfUHLiGACAGjfKbEdiL740UNGAQAUYB4DIhAVMA4CQwIQPcIJhmkiPyW99AOA9mB4JYYmQQBgqgDGB+DGYBwHgMAhMBQHIzJzsjGtEgUmukRgHGAuE2ZJjMplYBhjQKC8zAFAeHQGSQAgCgFDgAqdwNAAlU/M5SqZ1+5363PVVbko
Eyl/l3NZh5l1NM/2ZxwmauP/f/V7/d2FOM/MLfqBYHgaEv3Iso7nlM56q19Vavea/+fcv/h7mMvhbeLHddXBf9L8wCgMDAsAGgB24YoNbq0MrpaB9S8pgWhMhgGNae5l+9SXX3OMrMEYFkHAx/Rfyb1lvXf////////+e////////////+i+bAG1G/+JLjeN
bSYz7Z14yHsgtDnm1NwLj/i6pvNpMzhzp/X9qWILWZj/d4ylBC8eOP/3LFc/tZZ8oEYAIAxIBGf/zWMA/M3Myg6/P8AKA4AOZTSzRjqi+GGEFGYKwQKsLEC40PN2u87l/5VXakPO65nKmfzuPNZVr7VHTn9cu3plZOp/PK9SN2bR/Xcs7uVZ6kjU9h3tBjXT
hs7s73do+2auHO6qJ/NOl2dr7TxUmGuX/5unzlnMOVaVHWc/////Lmu5Vn+6KgClYSoQAE/U9dxs7t/////JKvNbuaIeGRJHGirrCAm04qJRrQCQKkt6oTK3HVv/zeMAYQJNyhv5/dNg4P2eyvZ1h5uvlhySSS3WpL0NuPNKV1WALEiKw73sALqM6QkLUVXQ
fa0CACDAAYyYHAQj6YEgmYNgKYAA0YPA8YRAecfwUbUEIFBkAgzFAOhUBQMCa+gIASSCVYKABrqJ7N2QK4SpXe87ttfpkTGSS9rcWfx17j+ZuPIbWVevN/KZ6PxumlkLeBpj/wPdgB/KV9IpEZHlLLFPnXaBrDmPa9+akHM7eGHtgprvcsOZS6xX3c7n+Msn
eXaftJSwJ/551KTGV9uSy+7EIa2YO2eVEou0+mcufmJBRU+eGH4fNSPvMPw/f/////leAqpdluv/ziMAEPvM2nv5nMtnGW7/4wBYXAJBiHQBhPABIhJJqYnRmK2BdRc9DLcKbuNWl5TX4jLaB/qJ9n6glyZAyplz1rDPmra4scXc9zAVNWyl3U+QuBDEocMB
gUy0wTi0rN5K8yyVDDoLMUCEMDIhAxg0CLrBABSRVVQAvwoEwZ4Viwc0p3aByoPZSy2YcqfhqLXaWzl3escKa/KZbNP9bhqHq8M0UNQ9Qv7flNmVQ9blM7NQzepr9Wzq1vuNLzK1vGahmdrS7Ol5TS7VN2rymv0tmrS1Iao2kxm9WxrS6vDMVjzvRNlTrKql
sTEVOB0WVUyXVMOVFojDuEanrtN3HCta6C4uOmAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/zGMAbAAACXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/zGMAyAAACXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFRBRwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAM","onRuntimeInitialized","log","onModuleAbo
rt","ModuleAbort","not compatible browser","onScannerReady","length","","(","x","points",", ","y","),","type",": ","|","onBarcode","onInitialized","onScannerStarted","onScannerStopped","onScan
nerDestroyed","onImageDecoded","onError","mediaDevices","enumerateDevices","enumerateDevices not supported","CannotEnumDevices","name","message","catch","kind","videoinput","label","Camera ","
deviceId","push","forEach","then","getSupportedConstraints","Supported Constraints:","width","video","resx","camera","ideal","height","resy","facingMode","id","Warning! Trying to set [facingMo
de] and [deviceId] at same time. Priority of deviceId","_onScannerReady","getVideoTracks","getSettings","canvas","createElement","videoSettings Ok","offsetWidth","offsetHeight","2d","getContex
t","canvas size|","CANVAS","style","position:absolute;top:0;left:0;margin:0;","setAttribute","appendChild","px","VIDEO","100%","playsinline","true","exVIDEOTAG","margin:0;padding:0;","
getUserMedia","loadeddata","addEventListener","srcObject","play","CannotAccessCamera","cannot access camera [navigator.mediaDevices, getUserMedia]","undefined","www.exmp.com Web-SDK Crea
te (WEBSDK ver:",", CORESDK ver:",")","scanner","key","InitLib","number","array","ccall","CannotInitLib","Cannot initialize barcode decoder SDK","barcode","viewport","getElementById","CannotCr
eateScanner","Cannot find viewport id","DIV","exmpTAG","position:relative;margin:0;padding:0;display:inline-block;line-height:0;","hasOwnProperty","ScanningRectLeft","left","scanningRect
","ScanningRectTop","top","ScanningRectWidth","ScanningRectHeight","light","applyConstraints","charCodeAt","sjis","decode","function","QRCode","data","utf-8","apply","fromCharCode","barcodeTyp
es","setProperty","buffer","barcodeTimeout","frameTimeout","ScannerNotReady","Scanner is not ready.","paused","pause","getTracks","stop","firstChild","removeChild","FreeLib","clearRect","HEAPU
8","exec","licenseInfo","edition","decoders","expDate","drawImage","getImageData","set","i32","getValue","bt","barcodeAtPoint","beep","Unrec","beginPath","moveTo","lineTo","closePath","fillSty
le","rgba(230, 0, 0, 0.5)","rgba(0, 230, 0, 0.5)","lineWidth","strokeStyle","rgba(120, 0, 0, 0.7)","rgba(0, 120, 0, 0.7)","fill","stroke","rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)","font","12px serif","textAlig
n","center","substring","...","fillText","now","drawTimeout","rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)","rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.9)","rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)","setLineDash","rect","orientation","beepData","min","o
nload","string","URL","webkitURL","GET","open","responseType","blob","onreadystatechange","readyState","status","UrlError","src","response","createObjectURL","send","DSScanner","assign","onerr
or","window.onerror","WindowOnError","resize","Module","wxm-sdk.s","arguments","thisProgram","./this.program","quit","preRun","postRun","object","locateFile","/","read","fs","path","
normalize","readFileSync","readBinary","argv","replace","slice","exports","uncaughtException","on","unhandledRejection","exit","inspect","[Emscripten Module object]","binary","href","location"
,"currentScript","blob:","indexOf","lastIndexOf","substr","responseText","arraybuffer","readAsync","setWindowTitle","title","print","bind","printErr","warn","ceil","i1","i8","i16","i64","float
","double","*","i","Assertion failed: ","_","Cannot call unknown function ",", make sure it is exported","stringToC","arrayToC","boolean","charAt","invalid type for setValue: ","invalid type f
or getValue: ","max","subarray","utf8","utf-16le","HEAP8","HEAP16","HEAP32","HEAPU16","HEAPU32","HEAPF32","HEAPF64","Cannot enlarge memory arrays. Either (1) compile with  -s TOTAL_MEMORY=X  w
ith X higher than the current value ",", (2) compile with  -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1  which allows increasing the size at runtime, or (3) if you want malloc to return NULL (0) instead of this a
bort, compile with  -s ABORTING_MALLOC=0 ","reallocBuffer","usingWasm","byteLength","get","prototype","getOwnPropertyDescriptor","call","TOTAL_STACK","TOTAL_MEMORY","TOTAL_MEMORY should be lar
ger than TOTAL_STACK, was ","! (TOTAL_STACK=","Memory","wasmMemory","shift","func","arg","dynCall_v","dynCall_vi","unshift","abs","floor","monitorRunDependencies","preloadedImages","preloadedA
udios","data:application/octet-stream;base64,","startsWith","sw-sdk.st","esx-sdk.temp.asm.js","the new buffer in mergeMemory is smaller than the previous one. in native wasm,
we should grow memory here","wasmBinary","both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed","ok","failed to load wasm binary file at '","'","arrayBuffer","same-origin","no native wasm support d
etected","no native wasm Memory in use","memory","global","global.Math","env","asm","wasm-instantiate","instantiateWasm","Module.instantiateWasm callback failed with error: ","instance","modul
e","failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: ","instantiate","instantiateStreaming","wasm streaming compile failed: ","falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation","asmPreload","grow","asmjs","tab
le","wasmTableSize","wasmMaxTableSize","Table","anyfunc","wasmTable","memoryBase","STATIC_BASE","tableBase","no binaryen method succeeded.","STATIC_BUMP","called","USER","LOGNAME","web_user","
PATH","PWD","HOME","/home/web_user","LANG","C.UTF-8","=","Environment size exceeded TOTAL_ENV_SIZE!","Pure virtual function called!","start","bufferSize","GMT","getUTCSeconds","getUTCMinutes",
"getUTCHours","getUTCDate","getUTCMonth","getUTCFullYear","getUTCDay","getTime","trap!","getTimezoneOffset","match","toTimeString","getFullYear","setTime","getDay","___errno_location","asmGlob
alArg","asmLibraryArg","_DecodeGraymap","_DecodePGM","_DecodeRGBA","_FreeLib","_InitLib","__GLOBAL__sub_I_PDF417DecoderMicro_cpp","___emscripten_environ_constructor","__get_daylight","__get_ti
mezone","__get_tzname","_emscripten_replace_memory","_free","_getLicenseData","_getResBarcodeType","_getResDQ","_getResData","_getResNum","_getResPoints","_malloc","_setProperty","stackAlloc",
"stackRestore","stackSave","ExitStatus","Program terminated with exit(","constructor","calledRun","setStatus","Running...","run","onAbort","stringify","abort(","). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 f
or more info.","abort","preInit","pop","noExitRuntime","lib","Base","mixIn","init","$super","extend","toString","WordArray","words","sigBytes","clamp","clone","random","enc","Hex","join","Lati
n1","Utf8","Malformed UTF-8 data","parse","BufferedBlockAlgorithm","_data","_nDataBytes","concat","blockSize","_minBufferSize","splice","Hasher","cfg","reset","finalize","HMAC","algo","Base64"
,"_map","create","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=","sin","MD5","_hash","HmacMD5","EvpKDF","hasher","keySize","iterations","update","compute","Cipher","_xformM
ode","_key","encrypt","decrypt","StreamCipher","mode","_iv","_prevBlock","BlockCipherMode","Encryptor","Decryptor","_cipher","encryptBlock","decryptBlock","CBC","Pkcs7","pad","BlockCipher","iv
","_ENC_XFORM_MODE","createEncryptor","createDecryptor","_mode","processBlock","padding","unpad","CipherParams","formatter","OpenSSL","format","ciphertext","salt","SerializableCipher","kdf","P
asswordBasedCipher","ivSize","execute","AES","_nRounds","_keySchedule","_invKeySchedule"]
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[]
[5]
[_0x172e[5]]
[4]
[5]
[_0x172e[5]]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[5]
[_0x172e[5]]
[9]
[10]
[_0x172e[10]]
[11]
[12]
[_0x4b9dx2a]
[14]
[_0x172e[14]]
[_0x4b9dx2d]
[13]
[_0x172e[13]]
[15]
[_0x4b9dx2a]
[14]
[_0x172e[14]]
[_0x4b9dx2d]
[16]
[_0x172e[16]]
[17]
[5]
[_0x172e[5]]
[_0x4b9dx2a]
[18]
[_0x172e[18]]
[19]
[20]
[9]
[21]
[22]
[23]
[24]
[25]
[26]
[27]
[28]
[_0x172e[28]]
[28]
[_0x172e[28]]
[29]
[_0x172e[29]]
[5]
[_0x172e[5]]
[30]
[31]
[30]
[28]
[_0x172e[28]]
[29]
[_0x172e[29]]
[42]
[_0x172e[42]]
[]
[41]
[_0x172e[41]]
[35]
[_0x172e[35]]
[36]
[40]
[_0x172e[40]]
[37]
[_0x172e[37]]
[11]
[38]
[37]
[_0x172e[37]]
[39]
[_0x172e[39]]
[34]
[_0x172e[34]]
[5]
[_0x172e[5]]
[32]
[_0x172e[32]]
[19]
[33]
[_0x172e[33]]
[28]
[_0x172e[28]]
[43]
[_0x172e[43]]
[28]
[_0x172e[28]]
[43]
[_0x172e[43]]
[5]
[_0x172e[5]]
[44]
[5]
[_0x172e[5]]
[45]
[_0x172e[45]]
[46]
[_0x172e[46]]
[45]
[_0x172e[45]]
[48]
[_0x172e[48]]
[47]
[_0x172e[47]]
[46]
[_0x172e[46]]
[45]
[_0x172e[45]]
[49]
[_0x172e[49]]
[48]
[_0x172e[48]]
[47]
[_0x172e[47]]
[50]
[_0x172e[50]]
[46]
[_0x172e[46]]
[50]
[_0x172e[50]]
[48]
[_0x172e[48]]
[51]
[_0x172e[51]]
[46]
[_0x172e[46]]
[50]
```

this is just tip of ice berg it entire code is this hex like values list
it returns gloabl variable DSScanner and I can use it in another js file but how I don't know how ?? It supposed to be Js extension is js but unreadable ....

Answer (score 1):

That's valid JavaScript, but you aren't meant to read it -- it's been shrunken and obfuscated so that you can't. If you want JavaScript that you can read, you can try searching for the **source code**, but if you can't find the source code then you're out of luck and won't be able to look at it.

If it creates a global variable, you probably just have to do include the JS file via a `<script>` tag that comes before the script tag with your JS and then you can use it like `DSScanner.someMethod()`.